# Python Module Import Issue

Tags: python

I'm using `python3` on a `Raspbian` distro.  When trying to use the `paramiko` module, I get an error message saying that I don't have the module to import.

> Error:
>  ImportError: No module named paramiko

I do have it:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/python $ sudo find / -name paramiko 2>/dev/null
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko

pi@raspberrypi:~/python $ pip3 install paramiko
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

I tried invoking it via `import paramiko` and from `paramiko import SSHClient`. Neither work.

Any suggestions on how to get this module to work?

Comment: Are you sure you're using python3.4 and not another release?

Comment: I know this might seem silly, but make sure you're using python3 and not 2.7.  `ls -l /usr/bin/python` will tell you what the link is pointed to.  Also try `/usr/bin/python3 -c "import paramiko"`.

Comment: it seems like you installed paramiko for Python3.4 and by default you are using different version of python to run your program, i guess Python2.7

Comment: I'm sure I'm using python3 :pi@raspberrypi:~/python $ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11). When I do "/usr/bin/python3 -c "import paramiko", I do not get an error.. Strange indeed.

Comment: ensure that your path is correct: `import sys; print(sys.path)` - if `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` is not on your path it's going to have a heck of a time importing it ;)

Comment: Path is in there: ['/home/pi/python', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Comment: How are you running your script? What is your script doing? With `/usr/bin/python3` you don't get any error, but is `python3` the same as `/usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: Andrea, to answer your question, yes it python3 = /usr/bin/python3

Very strange, it seems like after I imported it from the command line, I can invoke it from within the script without a problem. No more error message. Magically works now. Thanks for the import all, that was helpful.